# Aligning subreports in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that looks nicely aligned in the Visual Studio design screen, but when I check it in the preview screen or deployed on the report server, there are large gaps between each subreport and text box.

[image: Design screen]

[image: Preview Screen]

Is there any way to ensure that these are aligned in the actual report? Particularly in PDF form, which this will ultimately end up as.

Comment: I just tried this out now. I added two subreports to my main report aligned them perfectly using the properties for location and size. It seems as though you have done the same. When i previewed the report, they remained perfectly aligned. The only thing that seems off in your design view, is that the report headings seem to be seperate textboxes place on top of the subreport? Is this correct? This would cause the alignment to go out as the subreport's length will be variable depending on the contents of the subreport. Rather place your heading in the subreport itself.

Comment: I'd open and check your subreports individually to make sure that there is no space at the bottom of them - the report and page should abut the bottom of the tablix. Also take a look at whatever boxes/containers the subreports are in and make sure their "can grow" property is set to "no"

Comment: Make sure you put everything in a rectangle. That helps hold their positions.